# Pandas apply for a function that returns two values for two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I try to apply a function that does a transformation of a Series and also returns a number that allows to do the same transformation for other data. So I try to transform the column in df_ec and return the value into the table that describes columns (df_all_X). I do the following:

```
df_ec[df_all_X.index], df_all_X['lambda'] = df_ec[df_all_X.index].apply(lambda column: scipy.stats.boxcox(column))
```

But this returns the error  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). Also, I tried to transform the output to the list:

```
df_ec[df_all_X.index], df_all_X['lambda'] = df_ec[df_all_X.index].apply(lambda column: list(scipy.stats.boxcox(column)))
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: I want to add, that I saved the value as one variable, and then unpacked it in right dataframes, but I still be glad to see a more elegant solution

Comment: Take a look at the result_type argument in pandas.DataFrame.apply, unfortunately you can only use this when calling apply on a dataframe not a series, but it's trivial to rewrite you're lambda function so that it only acts on one column.